# SQL query to identify active records by filtering out rest of the records

Tags: sql, sql-server

There's one DB table 'SiteTransactions' (in Sql Server) which currently has the records in following sample format

| Id | TransactionType | SiteGroup | SiteName | TransactionTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Create | SG1 | TestSite1 | 2021-08-27 19:22:26.4318370 |
| 2 | Delete | SG1 | TestSite1 | 2021-08-28 09:22:26.4318370 |
| 3 | Create | SG2 | TestSite2 | 2021-08-28 10:12:26.4318370 |
| 4 | Create | SG1 | TestSite3 | 2021-08-29 19:22:00.4318370 |
| 5 | Delete | SG2 | TestSite2 | 2021-08-30 08:04:26.4318370 |
| 6 | Create | SG2 | TestSite2 | 2021-08-31 20:18:26.4318370 |
| 7 | Delete | SG2 | TestSite2 | 2021-08-31 20:20:26.4318370 |

This table stores all of the SiteName transaction details.
Both Create and Delete transactions are stored in this same table.
The problem here is that there is no dedicated identifier column which can tell whether a given SiteGroup-SiteName combination is currently active (i.e. not yet been deleted)

SiteName is always unique and no 2 **active** SiteNames can have same name UNLESS
a given SiteName has been previously deleted. 'TestSite2' in above table example.

### **Requirement**

The requirement as mentioned above is to get a list of active only SiteGroup-SiteName combination which have not been deleted yet.

Only way to do so is to check if any SiteGroup-SiteName combination has a Delete transaction type value or not and compare the TransactionTime.

The correct output for above sample table should be as follows since only TestSite3 after once created has not been deleted (hence it's considered to be active):

| Id | TransactionType | SiteGroup | SiteName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Create | SG1 | TestSite3 |

### **What I Tried**

Right now I've built following query by comapring TransactionTime timestamps:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(A.SiteName), A.SiteGroup, A.TransactionType, A.TransactionTime
FROM SiteTransactions A, SiteTransactions B
WHERE A.SiteName= B.SiteNameAND A.SiteGroup = B.SiteGroup 
AND A.TransactionType = 'Create'
AND A.TransactionTime> B.TransactionTime
ORDER BY A.TransactionTime DESC
```

But the problem with my query is that it also returns TestSite2 records (which has been deleted twice) due to the TransactionTime comparison check I have in place

What would be the tweak I need to make to get the required output?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_ and a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` - whicg applies to the whole selected rows. Skip those extra parentheses and Simply do `SELECT DISTINCT A.SiteName, A.SiteGroup, ...` to make code clearer!

Comment: Evolve! No one should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Comment: Search "first in group" as a start. You want last in this case (which is first in descending order) with a filter after finding first for the status of "create" (or perhaps not "delete" - you decide how based on your plan for TransationType column).

Comment: You can actually use parity. That means, You can simply count the number of time each SiteGroup-SiteName combination occurred in the table. If the count results in ODD number, then that's the combination you're looking for.

Comment: @SMor, I agree but since there's no unique column identifier to filter out the required results  I'm trying these approaches. Definitely there are better ways to achieve this than the the one being used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional windowed count for this

```sql
SELECT
  Id,
  TransactionType,
  SiteGroup,
  SiteName
FROM (
    SLEECT *,
      cnt = COUNT(CASE WHEN TransactionType = 'Delete' THEN 1 END)
              OVER (PARTITION BY SiteGroup, SiteName
                   ORDER BY TransactionTime ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM YourTable t
) t
WHERE cnt = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Row_Number ranking function to determine the type of the last transaction in each group.

```
Select ID, TransactionType, SiteGroup, SiteName
From 
(Select ID, TransactionType, SiteGroup, SiteName,
Row_Number() Over (Partition by SiteGroup, SiteName Order by TransactionTime Desc) As Num
From SiteTransactions) As t
Where Num=1 And TransactionType='Create'
```